# React Native Navigation Root issue with multiple views

Tags: react-native

Hello All I am facing an issue. 
I am trying to set different root in app.js file but it always open Home View. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code. Any help would be highly appreciable!

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, Text, AsyncStorage, AppRegistry } from "react-native";
import LoginContainer from "./Login/LoginContainer";
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
import Home from "./Dashboard/Home";

const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    login: { screen: LoginContainer },
    Home: { screen: Home }
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "login"
  }
);
const AppContainer = createAppContainer(RootStack);

class Demo extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isLoading: true,
      email: ""
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const email = AsyncStorage.getItem("email").then(email => {
      this.setState({
        isLoading: false,
        email: email
      });
    });
  }
  render() {
    if (this.state.isLoading) {
      return (
        <View>
          <Text>Loading..</Text>
        </View>
      );
    }
    if (this.props.email !== "") {
      return <Home />;
    } else {
      return <AppContainer />;
    }
  }
}
export default Demo;

AppRegistry.registerComponent("Demo", () => Demo);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

export default Demo;

Use this :

export default AppContainer;
or 
export default createAppContainer(RootStack);

Comment: it always goes to this line --- if (this.props.email !== "") {

Comment: if (this.state.email !== "") modify your code:props to state.

Comment: Add console.log(email) in componentDidMount and check it that its blank or have some value.

Comment: it is not printing anything

Comment: If email is blank,Then your if condition always true So Always open Home screen.

Comment: But even when it is not blank it still opens

Comment: if (this.state.email !== "") {
Console.log(‘if condition);
      return <Home />;
    } else {
Console.log(‘Else if condition);
      return <AppContainer />;
  }

Comment: Before your if condition.before if(this.props.email) code